# Git merge not applying all commits from branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I've been having allot of troubles with git merge lately. I'm finding that if it's a small branch with few changes then everything works as expected, but whenever I merge a branch that has touched allot of files and commits span days/ weeks I'm finding that when running 'git merge branch' all of the commits are not being applied so i have to go back through and determine what commits weren't applied and cherry-pick them. This seems wrong but I'm not quite sure what is going wrong with my work flow that makes me have to do this.

How do I make sure that all of my changes from a specified branch are "applied" when merging?

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit -

For those wondering git rebase was essentially what I was looking for. It wasn't that my changes were being overwritten or really anything that others were stating, my branch being so far behind master along with possibly my use of rebase -interactive to squash commits I think git was in a sense loosing reference to what had changed. Git rebase on my branch, checking out master then merging my branch to master fixed my problem of all changes not making it through a merge.

Update December 2020 -

I've updated my merge process to exclusively using the online github gui and creating pull requests, this has completely solved all merge issues I used to have.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about what `git merge` actually does. It creates a new commit that brings to sequences of commits together. It doesn't "apply" individual commits.

Comment: For us to help, you will need to describe a specific scenario in more detail.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That doesn't quite make sense because when I have a successful merge I see a merge commit stating the branch was merged then below I see any commits that were related to the branch that was just merged. So say i have 3 commits on branch a, merge branch a into master, on master I now have a merge commit along with the 3 commits that were on branch a

Comment: Those commits you see aren't just "related" to the branch that you merged. They are the exact same commits from that branch. Those commits aren't applied individually. Rather, their cumulative set of changes is applied as a new commit. See torek's answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I understand that but it doesn't help the fact that all of the commits are not being cumulatively applied as a new commit. I have to go back and cherry pick the commits that didn't make it through

Comment: So now that we are closer to being on the same page. It seems that the *changes* from the commits that you cherry pick aren't in the "cumulative commit". This means that for some reason those changes are being undone somewhere. We'll need some more details to help you sort this out. You can post a new question with diagrams similar to those in torek's answer below to describe your situation.

Answer (score 7):

Merge *never* "applies all of the commits"—that's not how it works.

We need to be a little careful here because `git merge` doesn't always merge, but the general case for a merge occurs when you have a series of commits that look like this:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

Here, you have commit `J` checked out because you have branch `our-branch` checked out.  So your index and work-tree match the snapshot in commit `J`.  You then run:

```
git merge their-branch
```

Git locates commit `L`, to which the name `their-branch` points.  Commit `L` *also* contains a snapshot, yet merge's job is to somehow combine *changes*.

In order to *see* changes, Git always needs to compare *two* commits.  Whatever is different between those two commits is what is different—a change.  But Comparing `J` and `L` directly doesn't work.

To get *useful* changes, `git merge` must first find the best *shared* commit, when starting from `our-branch` (commt `J`) and working backwards, and starting from `their-branch` (commit `L`) and working backwards.  Git calls this the *merge base*.  Here, the merge base commit is clear and obvious: it's commit `H`.

So Git now, in effect, runs *two* `git diff`s:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

The first changeset produces instructions that, if applied to (the snapshot in) commit `H`, would produce commit `J`.  The second produces instructions that would change `H` to `L`.

What `git merge` does now is to combine these two sets of instructions.  If we changed file *F*, and they didn't, Git uses our change to *F*, which is really just file *F* from commit `J`.  If they changed some other file and we didn't, Git uses their file.  Only when we both touched the *same* file does Git really have to work hard.

One way or another, Git applies the combined changes to the files found in `H` to construct a new index-and-work-tree.  In the cases where we both touched the same files, Git works harder, and really does combine changes.  If they conflict, Git leaves a mess in the index and work-tree and we have to clean up that mess and then finish the merge ourselves.  Otherwise Git goes on to make a new commit on its own.

Either way, once we finish or Git finishes, the new commit has a snapshot, like any other commit.  It's just one tiny bit different from any other ordinary commit: instead of pointing back *only* to commit `J`, it points back to commits `J` *and* `L` both:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

Having made commit `M`, the name `our-branch` now points to the new merge commit, which points back to `J` as usual (as its first parent) but also to `L` (as its second).

This first-and-second-parent-age affects a *future* merge.  Right now it's not important, but let's go on and add two more commits to each branch:

```
          I--J   N--O   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /    \ /
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L---P--Q   <-- their-branch
```

If you now run `git merge their-branch`, Git starts by doing the same thing it did last time, i.e., find a merge base.  The merge base is the best *shared* commit—a commit that is on *both* branches—but this time it's not commit `H`.  We start at `O` and work backwards: `O`, `N`, `M`, `J`-and-`L`, `I`-and-`K`, and so on.  Meanwhile, we start at `Q` and work backwards: `Q`, `P`, `L`, and so on.

But this time, commit `L` is on both branches.  So now commit `L` is the merge base.  Git will compare the snapshots in `L` and `O` to see what *we* changed, and compare the snapshots in `L` and `Q` to see what *they* changed.

So, in the end, the result of merging *now* depends on what is recorded in the commit graph from what you merged *then*, as well as the snapshots in each of the three critical commits.  Those three commits are:

- the current (`HEAD`) commit;
- the one you specified on your command line; and
- the merge base, which Git finds automatically.

If you want to see which commit Git found, run `git merge-base` with the `--all` option:

```
git merge-base --all our-branch their-branch
```

This should print one commit hash ID.  If so, that was the merge base that Git used.  (If it prints *more than one* hash ID, you're in a tricky merge situation, and we need a lot more words. :-) )

If you want to see *why* you got the result you did, find the merge base, and run the two `git diff` commands yourself.  (You'll want to redirect their output somewhere, and/or use `--name-status` first.)

Comment: Thank you that was very informative. I guess what I'm not clear on is how to make sure that all of my commits from say our-branch make it into the cumulative merge. I keep finding that changes from an entire commit aren't making it through the merge and I have to use git cherry-pick <commit> to have those changes take affect.

Comment: A typical way to "lose" a commit is to have it reverted somewhere along the line, so that the diff from base to tip does not show the desired change. Note that if some change *was* in the base snapshot (and is still in the tip) but was reverted in the *other* branch, now the diff from base to *their* tip shows that they thought it was important to *remove* the change, and Git has no reason not to believe them.

Comment: @bryan_stevens314 There are a few possibilities here: 1. The commit that you are cherry picking isn't on either branch that is being merged. 2. A commit after that commit reverses those changes so that the cumulative changes being merged doesn't contain the change you think it should.

Comment: It sounds very likely that scenario 2 is happening here, there are plenty of other people contributing to this project. But how do I ensure that even when this happens that ALL of the changes that I'm trying to merge from branch a into master make it into the cumulative merge? I've already had one time when I brought down a major feature of our site and lost user content because I didn't catch an improper merge.

Comment: There is no perfect answer to "how do I make sure no changes get undone somewhere along the way" but the best-answer-so-far, in the last 50 or so years, seems to be *have a lot of tests, and run them often*.

Comment: Changes aren't "getting undone somewhere along the way". I'm the only one working on this specific branch, when merging one would think that ALL changes from my branch would make it through the merge. The changes are there, they just aren't making it into the cumulative merge. Check the edit in my question for clarification.

Comment: Well, again, a `git merge-base --all` followed by some `git diff` operations would show you what Git sees. But if rebasing is more helpful—and in this case there's no one else working with those commits for whom rebasing would make *their* work harder, so there's no need for consensus—then go with rebasing!

Answer (score 3):

Git merge does *not* consider the separate revisions that make up a given branch that is being merged into another. Simplifying, it considers only 3 things:

```
- the latest common ancestor of both branches (latest revision that is present on both branches)
- diff between common ancestor and the tip of one of the branches
- diff between common ancestor and the ip of the _other_ branch you are merging.
```

So, if you have a commit that was (theoretically) not applied, it might be because the involved changed is already present on your current branch or that there is a later revision on the other branch that is taking it back?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it, I can be on a branch with a properly functioning feature with everything committed, checkout master, merge with resolving any merge conflicts being sure they're resolved correctly, then when retesting said feature it is now broken because there are commits that weren't applied

Comment: Then I think you need to better define what you mean with 'applied revision'... because when you merge two branches, each and every one of the revisions of both branches are part of the history of the resulting revision and that would match what i would defined as 'applied revision'.